# Is it appropriate to flip a coin hoping that Allah will influence it in order to make decisions?

Tags: halal-haram, allah

I sometimes flip a coin to make decisions and think that Allah (swt) would influence the coins landing so that I can make the right decision. Is this right, wrong, haram?

Comment: Allah is already influencing the coin and much else. It's called natural law.

Answer (score 3):

From my knowledge and what I've read so far, it is **haram** to believe that a coin toss would be influenced by Allah because it is similar to using divining arrows during the time of the Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) where the Arab pagans would do this to make decisions thinking it is divinely inspired by God.

Here's another post similar to yours: [What are "divining arrows" in Qur'an 5:3 and Qur'an 5:90?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45054/what-are-divining-arrows-in-quran-53-and-quran-590)

And Allah knows best.